# Module system vs module format

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, typescript1.6

I'm approaching modules for the very first time and I'm a little bit confused.

I read from various docs that there are several **modules systems**, like commonjs (sync), and requirejs (AMD). From ES6 plain javascript has its own module sys, which is based on commonjs.

Then I started studying webpack, that resolves dependency using commonjs or requirejs **module formats**, and from here starts my confusion: as far as I understand, **those two are module systems, they are designed to resolve the dependencies tree on its own;** it's their purpose.

**What is the sense to use the commonjs/requirejs format (aka syntax) and then implement webpack to resolve the graph?**

Answer (score 0):

CommonJS and AMD are both runtime module systems. Webpack is compiling your code, so you're not using it to resolve the graph specifically, you're using to create a build of an application from source files. To accomplish that, webpack 'understands' both types of modules so that it can analyze your code, identify dependencies, and bundle and optimize appropriately.

Webpack supports things that the original module systems don't: you can use more dynamic expressions to represent the module you're requiring; you can extend the `require` resolution behavior itself; you can specify an asynchronous runtime loading using its `require.ensure` syntax. Webpack's author could have defined a new module system to support these additional features, but then you'd have to rewrite all your existing source (and any third party modules) to accommodate the build tool. Instead, webpack is good about supporting whatever modules you already use, and giving you additional tools to handle more complex build needs.

Comment: Runtime  module system  means that only modules required at runtime will be loaded?

Comment: @nemus well, yes. I meant that CommonJS and AMD are both mechanisms that are intended to be used at runtime by your application code. In contrast to webpack, which is analyzing your code and transforming it into something new.